# Issue with TinyMCE Moxiemanager on PHP8

Tags: php, iterator, tinymce, tinymce-4, moxiemanager

We are using Moxiemanager with TinyMCE. But after upgrading on PHP8 we are facing error. We are getting the following error -

> Server returned an invalid response
>
> **Fatal error**:  During inheritance of IteratorAggregate: Uncaught MOXMAN_Exception: Return type of MOXMAN_Vfs_FileList::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/Vfs/FileList.php:38
> Stack trace:
> #0 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/Vfs/FileList.php(13): MOXMAN_Exception::throwRuntimeError()
> #1 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/AutoLoader.php(77): require('/sites/ssc.lara...')
> #2 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/Vfs/Local/File.php(277): MOXMAN_AutoLoader::autoload()
> #3 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/Commands/ListFilesCommand.php(148): MOXMAN_Vfs_Local_File->listFilesFiltered()
> #4 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/CommandCollection.php(39): MOXMAN_Commands_ListFilesCommand->execute()
> #5 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/CorePlugin.php(69): MOXMAN_CommandCollection->execute()
> #6 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/Handlers/JsonRpcHandler.php(74): MOXMAN_CorePlugin->execute()
> #7 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/CorePlugin.php(82): MOXMAN_Handlers_JsonRpcHandler->processRequest()
> #8 /sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/api.php(18): MOXMAN_CorePlugin->processRequest()
> #9 {main} in **/sites/ssc.lara/ssc/public/assets/libs/tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/Vfs/FileList.php** on line **13**
> Ok

It seems to be some issue with PHP's Iterator implementation. Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like it the plugin is simply not compatible with PHP 8.

Answer (score 2):

At `tinymce\plugins\moxiemanager\classes\Util\NameValueCollection.php`, change:

```
public function getIterator() {
    return new ArrayIterator($this->items);
}
```

to:

```
public function getIterator(): \Traversable {
    return new \ArrayIterator($this->items);
}
```

And at `tinymce/plugins/moxiemanager/classes/Vfs/FileList.php`, change:

```
public function getIterator() {
    return new ArrayIterator($this->getFiles());
}
```

to:

```
public function getIterator(): \Traversable {
    return new \ArrayIterator($this->items);
}
```

After these changes my Moxiemanager works fine (ver 2.1.8-28, PHP 8.1.8).

Comment: I'm using PHP 8.3 and I tried this, it fixes the console error but an error within pop up. Error: Undefined property: MOXMAN_Vfs_FileList::$items

Answer (score 0):

MoxieManager is does not support PHP 8 at this time. Moxie's developers are working on including PHP 8 support, and hope to have that release available later in Q1 2022.

Source: I work at Tiny

Comment: Hi @Tiny Lincoln, I have this console error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at api.php?action=language:1:1) with moxiemanager version 3.0.0.82 and on its changelog it says added support for PHP 8.2 and I'm using PHP 8.3.2. Any news on support for PHP 8.3? And I can't find github repo on moxiemanager.

Comment: Followed the answer from @noobeveryday fixes the issue on PHP 8.3.2.

Comment: After clearing browser cache, Error: Undefined property: MOXMAN_Vfs_FileList::$items on pop up.

Answer (score 0):

For php8.1,
at `tinymce/plugins/moxiemanage/classes/util/PDO.php`
I had to add

```
#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
```

to prepare and exec function in `PDO.php`. It works on php8.1.